# perl one liner + how to filter files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl

background: my target is to filter the files that contain the word - **old**

I want to print all files expect  the files that contain the old word (**capital or small letters** ) ,

according to the following rules:

if Az-zZ is before the old name or after the old name then line should be printed

if Az-Zz is after the old name and before old word  then line should be printed

if 0-9 is after the old name and before old word  then line should be printed

if 0-9 is before the old name and after old is non Az-zZ or 0-9 then line should not printed

if 0-9 is after the old name and before old is non Az-zZ or 0-9 then line should not printed

examples

```
  /DIR3/DATA/A4/Via/OOld/TriR.txt            --> should  be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/AOld1/Comne.txt          --> should be print
  /DIR5/DATA/A4/Via/BOld/TriR.txt     --> should be print
  /DIR5/DATA/A4/Via/aOld/TriR.txt      --> should be print
  /DIR5/DATA/A4/Via/1OldA/TriR.txt      --> should be print
  /DIR5/DATA/A4/Via/POld1/TriR.txt      --> should be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/1Old1/Comne.txt    --> should  be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/1Old1/Comne.txt    --> should  be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/Comne.txt    --> should  be print


  /DIR1/DATA/A4/Via/5Old/CentalS.txt   --> should not be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/Old1/Comne.txt    --> should not be print
  /DIR1/DATA/A4/Via/Old/CentalS.txt   --> should not be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/Old11/Comne.txt    --> should not be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/OLD@/Comne.txt    --> should not be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/.OLd/Comne.txt    --> should not be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/home/Comne.Old_txt    --> should not be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/home/Comne.old_txt    --> should not be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/home/Comne.0old_txt    --> should not be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/home/Comne.old6_txt    --> should not be print
  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/home/Comne___0old_txt    --> should not be print
```

Please advice how to implement this by perl one liner line 
syntax

```
 echo $PATH | perl one liner line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `echo $PATH |`, let's use `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}" |` (found [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3209/show-directories-in-the-path-one-per-line)), which prints the path line-by-line. The you can tag on this one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'if($_=~m/^(?!.*old).*|^.*?(?:[a-z]old|\dold[a-z\d]).*/i){print "$&\n";}'
```

which can be shortened to

```
perl -ne 'print if m/^(?!.*old).*|^.*?(?:[a-z]old|\dold[a-z\d]).*/i'
```

**Option 2**

This one should work directly with `echo $PATH`

```
perl -ne 'while(/(?:^|\G:\K)(?:(?!.*old)[^:]+|[^:]*?(?:[a-z]old|\dold[a-z\d])[^:]*)/ig){print "$&\n";}'
```

Comment: see the case in my example ( /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/Comne.txt    --> should  be print  )

Comment: Can you explain ` /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/Comne.txt` I don't understand the rule for this one to print (there is no `old`)

Comment: yes the most of the files not have "old" , in this case need to print the PATH

Comment: Ah, okay. Give me a minute. :)

Comment: NO PROBLEM I GIVE YOU MORE THEN 1 MIN TAKE YOUR TIME -:)

Comment: if you want you can use Borodin solution just need to fix it to print the PATH in case PATH not include "old"

Comment: Okay, I edited my one-liner to allow lines that don't have `old`.  Yes, you're right, using Borodin's path solution is another approach, but I was interested in adding a alternate one. :)

Comment: FYI: added an option that should work directly with `echo $PATH | `

Comment: I change the syntax to {print "$_";} , no need space in file   , +1 for you

Comment: @zx81 Why do you have a `while` loop in the answer? The `-n` option creates a loop automatically.

Comment: I find that `$_ =~ m/.../` is something of an anti-pattern in Perl. That is, it is a needlessly complicated way of writing the much more straightforward `/.../`.

Comment: @Barmar `Why do you have a while loop` It's by force of habit when `-n` feeds lines to Perl and we are looking for multiple matches on each single line. Here it's one line per match, so no need. Well spotted, thank you, fixed for Option 1. :) On Option 2, we work on one single line produced by `echo $PATH`, and I need to while loop to find the multiple matches, unless you have a more clever way.

Answer (score 2):

If the file paths are in a single file, then you can write

```
perl -ne'$w='old';print if /[a-z]$w|$w[a-z]|[0-9]$w[0-9]/i' myfile
```

or, if you prefer

```
perl -ne'print if /(.)old(.)/i && "$1$2" =~ /[a-z]|[0-9]{2}/i' myfile
```

Actually, it looks like you want to filter out members of the `PATH` environment variable, so you would want

```
perl -E'say for grep /(.)old(.)/i && "$1$2" =~ /[a-z]|[0-9]{2}/i, split /:/, $ENV{PATH}'
```

---

**Update**

I misunderstood your question. This should work for you

```
perl -lnE'/(.)old(.)/i && "$1$2" !~ /[a-z]|[0-9]{2}/i or say for /[^:]+/g'
```

I don't understand your requirement to both pipe `PATH` to it *and* specify a given path, so this works with either. Also you can put an input file after the command

Comment: echo /word | perl -ne'$w='old';print if /[a-z]$w|$w[a-z]|[0-9]$w[0-9]/i'    ( why this not print the /word ? )

Comment: EDIT My Question  /DIR4/DATA/A4/Via/Comne.txt    --> should  be print