# perl one liner + How to give standard output on perl line liner

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have the following perl line liner line

```
       echo $line | perl -ne 'while(.....){print "$_";}' >> $FILE
```

is it possible to give $? on the output of the perl line

so

```
 $? = 0 in case $_ print some value
 $? = 1 in case $_ is empty ( no value )
```

example:

```
  echo $line | perl -ne 'while(.....){print "$_";}' >> $FILE


  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
   then
     echo " new line in file "
   else
      echo " no new line in file"
  fi
```

the full syntax

```
  /usr/local/bin/perl -ne '$exit = 1;while($_=~m/(?:^|\G:\K)(?:(?!.*old)[^:]+|[^:]*?(?:[a-z]old|\dold[a-z\d])[^:]*)/ig){print "$_";}'
```

Comment: Call `exit($value)` in perl, that will set `$?` to `$value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "$line" | perl -ne 'BEGIN {$exit = 1;}
                         if(/(?:^|\G:\K)(?:(?!.*old)[^:]+|[^:]*?(?:[a-z]old|\dold[a-z\d])[^:]*)/i) {$exit=0; print "$_"; } 
                         END {exit($exit);}' >> "$FILE"
```

The value passed to `exit()` will be in `$?` in the shell.

Since you're using `-n` to create an input loop automatically, you need to put the code to initialize and return `$exit` in `BEGIN` and `END` blocks. You also shouldn't put `while` in your code, since that's part of the automatic loop.

Comment: can you edit please regarding my perl syntax - perl -ne 'while($_=~m/(?:^|\G:\K)(?:(?!.*old)[^:]+|[^:]*?(?:[a-z]old|\dold[a-z\d])[^:]*)/ig){print "$&\n";}'

Comment: Update question   +1 for you

Comment: See the updated answer. You confused me by putting `while` in your code, I didn't notice the `-n` option.

Comment: can you please update my code regarding your solution?

Comment: You're only reading one line. Why do you need `-n` to create a reading loop?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721200/perl-one-liner-how-to-filter-files

Comment: you don't need BEGIN,END blocks, just do it this way: perl -ne '/regex/ && $x++;print}{exit($x?0:1)'

Comment: @lihao That's ugly -- putting unbalanced braces in there, depending on it being textually appended to the automatic `while` statement. What's wrong with using BEGIN/END to make it clear what you're doing?

Comment: @Barmar, as a Perl lover, there is no need to stick to one solution. I just added an alternative way, that is.

Comment: Post the alternative as an answer. Putting it as a comment suggests that it's an improvement or correction of my answer.